# MergeMap conditionally

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Is there any RxJS way to conditionally call mergeMap in Angular:

```
return apiService.myApi.get().pipe(map(res => res), mergeMap(res => this.getPeople(res)))
```

to something like this:

```
return apiService.myApi.get().pipe(map(res => res), 
                        someCond ? mergeMap(res => this.getPeople(res)) : null)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can just return the original value with `of()` or use `EMPTY` to not emit anything further:

```
return apiService.myApi.get().pipe(
  map(res => res),
  mergeMap(res => someCond ? this.getPeople(res) : of(res)),
);
```

Comment: thanks @martin it worked like earlier i did a full if statement instead of ternary operator, was not thinking of  of(res)